# How can I detect laughing words in a string?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to detect laughing words like "hahahaha" and "lolololol" in a string.

Currently I'm using the following regex:

```
^((.*?)|)(\b[ha]|\b[lo])(.*?)$
```

However, this doesn't work for my purposes. It *works*, but it also matches words totally unrelated to laughter, such as 'kill', because it simply looks for any word that contains the letters l, o, h, a.

How can I detect laughing words (like "hahaha" or "lololol") in a string?

Comment: @Bill, when *everyone* understands the question one way except for you, maybe the problem isn't everyone else, but your reading comprehension.

Comment: @Bill, I am sure the OP will be glad to state the opposite as he just accepted a solution wich doesn't do what you understood. Read the initial question over and over again and you will get it...

Comment: Sorry, if my grammar is not perfect, my main language is not english

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with this pattern:

```
\b(?:a*(?:ha)+h?|(?:l+o+)+l+)\b
```

or better if your regex flavour support atomic groups and possessive quantifiers:

```
\b(?>a*+(?:ha)++h?|(?:l+o+)++l+)\b
```

Comment: Why all the non-capturing groups? Regex is hard enough to read already. I would remove them.

Comment: Don't forget to match hah, hahah, lool, loooooooll, etc

Comment: @Bohemian: Because you don't need to capture anything

Comment: @Patashu, Well in that case we could also say any combination of `ha` or `lo` letters... haaahahahaah lloooooooolllllll, but at some point...

Comment: @Bill, reread the question. That's why your answer got downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @plalx and ALL -- question states --- "`that contains the letter l,o,h,a`"

Comment: This regex matches words such as "happen" as well

Comment: @TitusPullo: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

`\b(a*ha+h[ha]*|o?l+o+l+[ol]*)\b`

Matches:

```
hahahah
haha
lol
loll
loool
looooool
lolololol
lolololololo
ahaha
aaaahahahahahaha
```

Does not match:

```
looo
oool
oooo
llll
ha
l
o
lo
ol
ah
aah
aha
kill
lala
haunt
hauha
louol
```

Answer (score 6):

To keep it simple, because the solutions posted may be overly complicated for what you want to do: if the only thing you count as "laughing words" are `ha`, `haha`, etc. and `lol`, `lolol`, `lololol`, etc., then the following regular expression will be sufficient:

```
\b(ha)+|l(ol)+\b
```

This assumes a regex dialect in which `\b` represents a word boundary, which you seem to be using.

Comment: +1 This is the most effective solution. Keep things simple. This sounds like it's in the context of a game, and your players will understand how to trigger the game's laughing reaction if they want to. This doesn't have to be a flawless humour-detection AI.

Comment: Often someone will type lolololololool and typo the end so it isn't a perfect repetition, though.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, I tried to do it in this way:

```
import re

re.sub(r"\b(?:a{0,2}h{1,2}a{0,2}){2,}h?\b", "<laugh>", "hahahahha! I love laughing")
```

`>> <laugh>! I love laughing`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```py
regex_pattern = "\b(?:a*(?:ha)+h?|h*ha+h[ha]*|(?:l+o+)+l+|o?l+o+l+[ol]*)\b"
```

you can try can in this:

```
sentance = hhhaaahhhaaa
```