# Sed: Matching words with any permutation of two characters

Tags: regex, macos, unix, sed, corpus

I'm trying to match all laughing words in a corpus and convert them into one standard word, like "haha". Examples of laughing words are

```
jaja
jjjaaja
aaajajja
ajaj
```

and so on. I think all I need is a way to match all words, of any length, that contain only *j* and *a*, in any order and or amount. I've tried the regex I found in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453522/how-can-i-detect-laughing-words-in-a-string) but none of them worked. One of the answers inspired me to try this

```
sed 's/ a*j*a*j*[ja]* / haha /g'
```

Which converts half of the words in the corpus into "haha". I've messing around with this command for a while and trying different things, but I can't seem to get it. So I'd really appreciate your help.

BTW I'm using OSX El Captain.

Comment: This did not work; it did not match anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sed command:

```
sed 's/\b[ja]\+\b/haha/g' file
haha
haha
haha
haha
```

However keep in mind that this will command any combination of `a` and `j`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this did not work for me. I suspect my version of sed doesn't recognize these `\b`s. Weirdly though, this seems to work: `sed 's/ [ja]+ / haha /g'` . I'll keep the question open for a while in case there's a better solution, for example, one that doesn't require two spaces around the laughing word.

Comment: Yes you need `-E` option on OSX. It's it still not working for you? Why are you matching spaces here? Better you edit the question and provide the real input.

Comment: It turns out that OSX's sed does not support `\b`, so I installed GNU sed and tried your command: it worked! Thanks buddy. 

I included spaces because I'm working with tweets and the delimiter between words is a white space (I removed punctuation).

Comment: Yes that's true. Even I'm on OSX and have installed gnu sed using `home brew`