# Regex to match only repeating group (laughing expressions)

Tags: regex, string, match, words

I would like to use regex to identify laughing/funny words, such as: `ahahah` or `hahaha`. So the idea is to identify repeating `ah` or `ha` or `lol`, etc. In addition I would also like to identify `ah ah ah`. 
I looked at a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16453522/how-can-i-detect-laughing-words-in-a-string), however it did not include spaces between n-grams (e.g. `ah ah`). I was able to define:

```
'(?:ha)+|(?:ah)+|(?:lol)+'
```

This expression does work, however it provides many false positives. For example, it matches `happen` or `having` or `hax`. How can I identify only words defined by repeated `ah` or `ha`. Furthermore, can I use the same expression to catch `ha ha ha`?

Comment: Word boundaries `\b(ha ?)+\b`?

Comment: [You may use `\b(ha|ah|lol)(?:\h*\1)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/BWGYSU/1)

Comment: Try [`\b(?:(?:a|h)\[ah \]+|\[lol\]+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Wb7zx3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for word boundaries without them matching parts of a word is likely to happen:

```
\b(?:(?:ha+|ah+|lo+l) ?)+\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/EHkJe2/4)

Comment: It does partially work as it does not match "ah" or "ha". Would it be possible to expand the expression so that it could match `loooool` or `ahhhhhahhhhh`?

Comment: Please check update.